# Error With FileDataStore Not Found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, calendar, google-calendar-api, uwp

I am creating a UWP app to pull back a list of events from google calendar and hitting an error with the following block of code

```
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar},
                "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Books.ListMyLibrary"));
```

The "FileDataStore" is flagging up the following error

```
 The type or namespace name 'FileDataStore' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

But I have the following using statement

```
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
```

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the Google API support Windows Universal apps? I couldn't find any support information just browsing their generated docs.

Comment: As far as i know it is supported however I also can't find any documentation on it.  I have seen a couple examples of apps out there but no code to check out

Answer (score 1):

James,
Typically with Visual Studio, if you have the correct using statement and are still getting that error, you need an assembly reference.

According to [this article, in step 3,](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-we-can-use-google-calendar-in-asp-net-through-google-ap/) you need to add a reference to the Google Data Api assemblies for your project.